How Do You Get Same Answers From Azure AI Foundry Project via API That You Get In Chat Playground
I have a project in Azure AI Foundry where I've deployed chatgpt 3.5. In the playground, I've also added another data source, which is just an upload of a PDF document. It ingested and indexed the doc, and when I issue queries in chat playground I get responses that include data from that PDF. The problem is when I make a connection to the project via REST in my web app (using AzureOpenAIClient, ChatClient and StreamingChatCompletionUpdate). All of the responses I get back are from chatgpt only, and do not include any data that was in the PDF. Why is that, and/or what configuration changes do I need to support this scenario?

I think the answer might be that it needs to be combined into a prompt flow.  I say "I think" because I've gone through the steps to create one, but Azure won't deploy it, so I can't verify for sure.  That being said, I don't understand why it works in a simple Chat Playground without a prompt flow. For more info on creating a prompt flow, you can follow the MS Learn tutorial here:  https://microsoftlearning.github.io/mslearn-ai-studio/Instructions/04-Use-own-data.html.

in the chat playground, there should be a view code option/button (left top) that will generate corresponding code block that you can call. The restful openai call should contain AI search index parameters that references document knowledge base. Worth giving it a try.

Thanks qkfang, that was a great suggestion, I hadn't noticed the Code<> option in the playground before.  Unfortunately, the code it generates does not work, so something probably just needs to get synced up between the Nuget packages and what's working in the playground.  Appreciate the answer.
